# What are those plugs called, and who is the manufacturer?

Tags: connector, plug

These are called "Zwerg-Stecker" and "Zwerg-Kupplung" respectively in German, but I've never seen them anywhere else. It basically translates to "dwarf plug" and "dwarf socket".

[image][image]

It is a 2.6mm mini banana plug system, I remember seeing them on some lab equipment in Uni, but never seen them anywhere else. We use banana plugs quite often, whether it's 4mm or the smaller 2mm system. Unfortunately, making cables ourselves it sometimes a bit of a hassle, since they're more or less designed to be pre-confectionated wires. Now, I was thinking of introducing this Zwerg system, since it is designed to be not confectionated at all. Instead, you're supposed to cut your own wires and put the plugs on it.

It has a weird size, though. 2.6mm diameter and a very short plug. I haven't seen complete cables made with Zwerg plugs, but I have seen them quite often in lab equipment, where people would make their own cables because of a requirement in non-standard lengths, etc...

I don't know the manufacturer, I've seen them in a couple of electronics stores, but that's pretty much it.

Comment: I've never seen these plugs, but I've often used what we call "pin-tip" jacks, which are a fairly small alternative to bananas. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "confectionated." If that were a word in English, it would probably mean "sugar-coated".

Comment: These were very popular in Asia in some electronics labs I've been to. Don't seem to find them around the US now, though.

Comment: @ThePhoton Translating through italian (:D) means something that comes directly with a closed case from the manufacturer, and not suited for unmounting or modifying (if you think to bananas - amazing we use the same name :P - they haven't got the screw that allows to extract the wire).

Comment: I've seen bananas in multiple styles: pre-assembled and molded to the wire insulation; solder-assembled, and with screws like in OP's photo. I haven't seen pin-tips with the screw-down attachment, but I have seen both solder-assembled and molded-on styles.

Comment: @polemon: Where did you find the photo?

Comment: It would be nice to have an EE dictionary.

Comment: suggest "confectionated" = "tinned" or soldered?

Comment: I meant pre-assembled. Those aren't, so you have to put the wire into the plugs and sockets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are mini-banana plugs and jacks. Pomona is one company that makes them:

http://www.pomonaelectronics.com/pdf/d2945_100.pdf

http://www.pomonaelectronics.com/pdf/d2143_1_01.pdf

Digi-Key stocks them.

Comment: Hmm, it seems those are called "mini-banana" plugs and jacks. I was calling the 2mm system "mini" and this just "Zwerg". (2mm banana system and Zwerg are incompatible, mind you.)

Answer (score 2):

Those look very much like the connectors that Märklin uses for their model trains, the good old analog version.

Comment: +1. I've seen them a lot on electric toys, but hardly in any lab or on any sort of electronics test equipment.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase them [here](http://www.train-li-usa.com/store/bprolineb-banana-plugsjacks-p-1102.html).

LGB makes them for help with wiring up their train lighting systems and much more.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this, it was a great help. The Märklin name seems well connected with these connectors. Since the links were dead I've found some current sources.

[Conrad](https://www.conrad-electronic.co.uk/ce/en/overview/0222221/Jack-Connectors?filterPin%20diameter=2%2C6%20mm) have a good selection and [Reichelt](https://www.reichelt.com/gb/en/Banana-Plugs-Toy-Plugs/2/index.html?CCOUNTRY=447&LANGUAGE=en&ACTION=2&LA=3&GROUPID=7473;SID=93Wwa9KawQATYAAHUwpSs42dba7e1271e5a11ff0a582696c6d00a) also carry a range of them. Their name varies on the supplier and they seem linked to German technical toys in particular.